# php replace parameter

Tags: php

```
$s = "{$i}<br>";

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    f($s);
}

function f( $a )
{
    echo $a;
}
```

How can I replace `$i` with current value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `$s = "{$i}<br>";` inside the loop as:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $s = "{$i}<br>";
  f($s);
}
```

Comment: i get $s from other param, here it's just example